# Auth0-react failing silently on succesful login

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I’ve set up `auth0-react` in our application following instructions from a number of tutorials. Clicking the login button succeeds - I can see `Success Login` events in my user’s history. But the `Auth0Provider`’s reducer still has `isAuthenticated` set to `false` an no user populated.

My `Auth0ProviderWithHistory` looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Auth0Provider, Auth0ProviderOptions } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

type Auth0ProviderWithHistoryProps = React.PropsWithChildren<{}>;

const Auth0ProviderWithHistory = (props: Auth0ProviderWithHistoryProps) => {
  const domain = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN;
  if (!domain) {
    throw new Error("Could not get auth domain from env");
  }
  const clientId = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID;
  if (!clientId) {
    throw new Error("Could not get auth client ID from env");
  }

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const onRedirectCallback: Auth0ProviderOptions["onRedirectCallback"] = (appState) => {
    navigate(appState?.returnTo || window.location.pathname);
  };

  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      authorizationParams={{ redirect_uri: window.location.origin }}
      clientId={clientId}
      domain={domain}
      onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
};

export default Auth0ProviderWithHistory;
```

I'm calling `loginWithRedirect` in an `onClick` callback. As I said, I can see successful login events in my user's history, and the redirect appears to  work, but the Context is not being populated.

Comment: Did you get any error logs? Can you share those if any?

Comment: @Kalana no there were no errors in the logs